# A plane with two points and a line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, plane-geometry

I have $A(-2,1,0)$ and $B(7,-2,k)$ and
$$\ell: x = (-4,-5,-2)+t(1,-2,0)$$

I need to find a $k$ so that A and B and $\ell$ are in the same plane.

I thought this doesn't make sense because you can create a plane with two different lines. Therefore, I will choose each time a different $k$, will get a different line ($AB$), and I can create a plane who has inside $\ell$ and $AB$.

I don't seem to get the problem pretty well. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Two lines are not necessarily coplanar

Comment: @Bernard Right... Therefore I need to find a $k$ where AB cuts $\ell$?

Comment: Yes. You'll obtain a system of 3 linear equations in two unknowns, depending on the parameter $k$, and the values of $k$ will  have to satisfy the compatibility conditions.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: Choose $2$ points of the line $\ell$: $C = (-4,-5,-2), D = (-3,-7,-2)$, and write an equation of the plane $\alpha$ passing through $3$ points: $A, D, C$, and then plug the coordinates of the point $B$ into the equation of the plane $\alpha$ to find $k$.